# Do Bayesian Network perfect maps need to be chordal?

Tags: self-study, causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

In *Probabilistic Graphical Models* by *Koller* and *Friedman*, there is a proposition -

> The PDAG $\mathcal K$ returned by Build-PDAG is necessarily chordal.

Build-PDAG is an algorithm that builds the equivalence-class-PDAG for the perfect map, if one exists.

My confusion is with the definition of chordal graph.

If a PDAG is chordal, when its undirected version is chordal (which is the definition the text also gives), it implies that a perfect map of below type is not possible. Whence my question - do BN perfect maps need to be chordal.

[image]

However, if chordal graph is only for undirected graphs, then the above theorem is appropriate. The loop $A-B-X-C-A$ will definitely contain an immorality and hence the edges for the immorality will become oriented by Build-PDAG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. Bayesian Network perfect maps need not be chordal. And your example is a case in point. At least, if chordality is really defined as the chordality of the undirected version.

So this is a bit confusing. But in the text following the cited statement, what they actually use is the fact that the *undirected components of the chain graph $\mathcal K$ are chordal*. So my guess is that that's what they refer to by "$\mathcal K$ is chordal".

Then, in your example, $\mathcal K$ would be the chain graph:

[image]

and the only nontrivial undirected component present is:

[image]

And this component is indeed chordal. And that, IIUC, is all they need in their proof of Theorem 3.10.

Comment: I agree to frank's take on the interpretation of chordality for PDAG(s) in this context; it makes sense here. However, I also found the exact portion where they define chordal graphs for graphs that contain directed edges. **Definition 2.25** in the text-


*A graph $\mathcal K$ is said to be chordal if its underlying undirected graph is chordal.*


So I think the author's definition of chordal graphs, for graphs with directed edges, is not very clear here.

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty Yes, I read this definition. But I could not find a definition of "underlying undirected graph".